# Given a list of indices, how can I remove those elements from std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Let me first describe the higher level goal. I have a matrix (I use `std::vector<std::vector<bool>>` as the representation) of booleans.

I want to remove all rows where the entire row is all `true` values.

Currently, I do:

```
bool is_row_true(const vector<bool>& row) {
  return all_of(row.begin(), row.end(), [](bool val) {
    return val;
  });
}


for (int i = 0; i < mat.size(); ++i) {
    if (is_row_true(mat[i])) {
      std::erase(mat.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

However, this seems rather inefficient. Instead of this, I was consider getting the list of indices whose row is all true, and passing in the list of indices and removing all those rows simultaneously. Is there a way to do this in functionality in the containers library?

Comment: [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: I see. Is this suggesting to do `std::remove_if(mat.begin(), mat.end(), vector<bool>(mat[0].size(), true))` ?

Comment: Please be sure you've read and understood the question before closing as a duplicate. This is not a duplicate of the question that it was previously closed as duplicating.

Comment: @24n8 *"Is this suggesting to do [...]"* -- My first attempt would be `std::remove_if(mat.begin(), mat.end(), is_row_true)` then give it to the compiler for a syntax check. (Sometimes a quick compile is easier than looking up the syntax documentation.)

Comment: @JaMiT It works with `remove`. `remove_if` API is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> mat{ {true, false},{true, true}, {true, true} };
    std::erase_if(mat, [](auto& x) {return std::all_of(x.begin(), x.end(), [](bool val) {return val; }); });
}
```

It's simpler than the remove-erase idiom but is only avail c++20 or higher.